# How to persistently use R1C1 styling in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I want Excel to be permanently labelled using R1C1 notation for cell positions. However, the changes I make by going to File > Options > R1C1 setting only work as long and the project is open. Once I close Excel, the option reverts to the original settings.

How can I make it persist?

It would be even better if I could show columns as A(1), B(2).... etc.

Comment: What version of Office did you use? I tested with my Office 365, I set the R1C1 option and close- reopen, the setting still working.